# Rendering Module not displaying video (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: sitecore-client

On Edit mode, I want to add a video from Global reference. After adding the rendering module, and selecting the video, when the page reloads, the rendering module was added but it's not displaying the video. I'm new to Sitecore, please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what the **rendering module** is. Can you give more information on it. Are you adding a video via the rich text editor or did you get a video player from the market place?

Comment: I'm using limelight video player.

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. If possible include some of the source code you are using. Is this your code or you get it from somewhere? Describe what you have already tried.

Comment: Don't assume OP knows the code, there is no indication of that

Answer (score 2):

It might be perfectly normal that the video does not show while you have Sitecore in edit mode. Sitecore manipulates the page to achieve the in-line editing experience and this might or might not be compatible with the video player in use.

After adding your video module, save your changes. Then try switching to the more compatible "preview" mode and check your results.

[image]

More info on basic editing experience here: [Preview a webpage](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/preview_a_webpage)

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Is this a new behavior of the latest Sitecore version?